# (X,Y) in a grid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, grid

Isn't there a trick that may help me show a component inside a grid by using X,Y coordinates ?

Thanks in advance

Miloud Bel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a canvas inside a grid and then set controls inside the canvas with x,y coordinates.

This however, although doable, is **not** a good way for control layout.

I would recommend creating rows and columns for the grid, and placing the controls inside the grid cells by assigning a grid row and grid column to the control.

Usualy one grid is enough per page, which is the layout grid available by default, you just have to add rows and columns according to your needs.

If you have a very simple layout, you can just use a stack panel.

Here is an overview of the 3 (canvas, stack panel, grid): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-2-using-layout-management.aspx

Comment: Brilliant and full explanation. Thank you buddy ;)

Comment: If you go down the route of setting coordinates explicitly you're likley to make handling orientation changes more difficult as you'll have to re-lay out controls yourself. You're also likley to have more problems when you need to support devices with smaller screens.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your point. And you're totally right about it. Thus, I've replaced my canvas with a stackPanel and followed a completely different approach.